# Optimized way of splitting a string with minimum iterations

Tags: python

Let's say 's' is a user input string and 'n' is a user input number which is less than  the length of the string.
Define a function strsplit(s,n) (which will accept both the user input as arguments) and 
split the input string in to multiple substrings each of n length seperated by a space character.

```
example:
lets say s="abcdefghij"
and n=3
then functions strsplit(s,n) should print 
abc def ghi j
```

Optimized solution with minimum iterations which I can find is as below

```
def strsplit(s,n):
 ln=len(s)
 for i in range(0,ln,n):
   print(s[i:i+n],end=" ")
```

Can be there an improved and optimized solution that the above one?

Comment: @sshashank124 
Yes its a similar question. But in this solution, function is yeilding a generator object which I need to collect in to some 
variable , lets say as below

 snew=chunks(str, n)

And then I need to do " ".join(snew) to get the output in required form.
So does that the optimized way with minimum cost ?

Comment: Best way to know is to benchmark. No point in speculating